# Trying to read a file thats in the directory

Tags: java

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:/Users/Benny/IdeaProjects/SoftDevProj/SoftDevGame/Rooms.txt");

    public Game() throws IOException {
        map = new ArrayList<Room>();
        String room1 = Files.readAllLines(path).get(1);
        String room1Desc = Files.readAllLines(path).get(2);
```

Sorry if this is a little confusing I can only post so much, but Im trying to get rid of the "C:/Users/Benny/IdeaProjects/SoftDevProj/SoftDevGame"
in my code by just looking at the Rooms.txt file.
I'm basically trying to do this:
Path path = Paths.get("Rooms.txt")
and have it work but I've tried everything is there any way I can fix this, by having it not be a fixed file location?

Comment: If this file is part of your project, the concept you might be looking for is "resource files". Have a random tutorial: https://mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/

Comment: You can do `Path path = Paths.get("Rooms.txt")` when Room.txt is in the same folder where your Java file is (e.g. in the src folder in an IDE like IntelliJ).

Comment: I've tried this but I still get the file not found error if it is in the folder as well.

Comment: I have also seen that exact link while trying to research unfortunately it all led me back to where I started with it not being found.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash That is completely wrong.  There is no guarantee of what the current directory will be when the program is running.

Comment: Do not call Files.readAllLines(path) twice.  Reading files is a slow operation.  Do it only once.

Comment: @VGR You are right. What I have mentioned works only within the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to include any resources alongside your class files so that they can be accessed via the [`ClassLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassLoader.html). If building with Maven or Gradle you would store the file at `src/main/resources/Rooms.txt` which would then get packed inside the jar file alongside the class files.

You could then access via

```java
try (InputStream in = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Rooms.txt")) {
  if (in == null) throw new RuntimeException("Could not find Rooms.txt on classpath");
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
  String[] lines = reader.lines().toArray(String[]:new);
  String room1 = lines[1];
  String room1Desc = lines[2];
  ...
}
```

It's probably best if you change your `Rooms.txt` to `Rooms.json` and use a json parsing library to read/write the json. Then you could have complex/nested data structures in the file. Eg

```json
{
  "rooms": [
      { "name": "room1", "description": "A red room" },
      { "name": "room2", "description": "A blue room" }
  ]
}
```

Comment: as I tried to do that I got this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.io.BufferedInputStream cannot be cast to class java.nio.file.Path (java.io.BufferedInputStream and java.nio.file.Path are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap') and its now refereing to the change I had to make here : String room1 = Files.readAllLines((Path) path).get(1);

Comment: An `InputStream` is not a `Path`. See my updates

Comment: Do not do getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Rooms.txt").  For compatibility with modular applications, do `Game.class.getResourceAsStream("/Rooms.txt")` instead.  Class.getResourceAsStream will always have better support than ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream.